# How to do histogram equalization to DICOM images read with SimpleITK

Tags: python, opencv, dicom, itk, simpleitk

I'm trying to do histogram equalization to all images read from a *.nii.gz file.

I have tried this code:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
flair_file = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/.../FLAIR.nii.gz'

images = sitk.ReadImage(flair_file)
print("Width: ", images.GetWidth())
print("Height:", images.GetHeight())
print("Depth: ", images.GetDepth())

print("Dimension:", images.GetDimension())
print("Pixel ID: ", images.GetPixelIDValue())
print("Pixel ID Type:", images.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
```

With this output:

```
Width:  240
Height: 240
Depth:  48
Dimension: 3
Pixel ID:  8
Pixel ID Type: 32-bit float
```

But when I try to do histogram equalization with OpenCV I get errors:

```
images_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(images)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(images_array[24], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Output:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<1>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = (cv::impl::<unnamed>::SizePolicy)2u; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

So, I have tried this other code:

```
images_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(images)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(images_array[24], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
output = cv2.equalizeHist(images_array[24])
```

But I get this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:3429: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'equalizeHist'
```

How can I do histogram equalization to those DICOM images (maybe not using OpenCV, and using instead SimpleITK)?

**UPDATE:**
When I run this command:

```
print(images_array[24].shape, images_array[24].dtype)
```

I get this:

```
(240, 240) float32
```

Comment: What's `print(images_array[24].shape, images_array[24].dtype)`?

Comment: are you sure the images are BGR? my guess is that DICOM images are 16 bit greyscale, a lot are like that. If that is the case, you cannot do `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, because it is already gray and does not have 3 channels. And you can't do `cv2.equalizeHist` because it is not 8 bit greyscale... Please print what HansHirse recommend to see what is happening.

Comment: Hmmm, well I think you will have to implement it yourself :( At least is one channel, so it is not so complicated. Since it is a float mat, you have to create some bins (you decide the number of bins. Then get the cdf of the bins (ordered from less intensity to high intensity) and normalize it. When it is an 8 bit image is easier, since you only need to count the occurrence of each intensity, so in that case one has 256 bins and is easy to normalize.... are the values of your image discrete? what is the range? 0-255? 0-65536?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleITK does have an AdaptiveHistogramEqualization function, and it does work on float32 images.  Here's how you could use it:

```
new_images = sitk.AdaptiveHistogramEqualization(images)
```

Note that this would do equalization across the whole 3d image.  If you wanted to do it on a slice-by-slice basis, it'd look something like this:

```
new_images = []
for z in range(images.GetDepth()):
    new_images.append(sitk.AdaptiveHistogramEqualization(images[:,:,z])
```

UPDATE:  As pointed out by @blowekamp, AHE doesn't produce a global histogram equalization across the whole image, but a local equalization.  Here is some example code that show's how to use the HistogramMatching function, as described by him, to achieve global histogram equalization.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

# Create a noise Gaussian blob test image
img = sitk.GaussianSource(sitk.sitkFloat32, size=[240,240,48], mean=[120,120,24])
img = img + sitk.AdditiveGaussianNoise(img,10)

# Create a ramp image of the same size
h = np.arange(0.0, 255,1.0666666666, dtype='f4')
h2 = np.reshape(np.repeat(h, 240*48), (48,240,240))
himg = sitk.GetImageFromArray(h2)
print(himg.GetSize())

# Match the histogram of the Gaussian image with the ramp
result=sitk.HistogramMatching(img, himg)

# Display the 3d image
import itkwidgets
itkwidgets.view(result)
```

Note that itkwidgets allows you to view a 3d image in a Jupyter notebook.  You can see the histogram of the image there.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for.

Comment: The AdaptiveHistogramEqualization does local contrast enhancement. The classic histogram equalization is a *global* intensity mapping. The filter you are looking for is the `HistogramMatchingImageFilter`(https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1HistogramMatchingImageFilter.html). For a reference image you can convert `np.arang(0.0, 1.0, 256, dtype=float)` to a sitk image.

Comment: @blowekamp Do you know if there is a way to convert a SimpleITK image to a OpenCV image? In other words, is there a way to use a SimpleITK image with the `cv2.equalizeHist()` method? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel You can't convert directly from SimpleITK to OpenCV.  You have to go through numpy.

Comment: @DaveChen When you say "Note that this would do equalization across the whole 3d image", you mean that it will do equalization on each of its images. If it has 48 images, it will equalize all of them, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: @DaveChen In your comment you say "You have to go through Numpy". Do I have to add a new dimension to the array and that's it? Thanks.

Comment: It is equalizing the whole 3-d block of pixels at once.  It's making a single histogram of all the pixels, and then using that histogram for adjusting the pixel intensities.  You original 'images' variable is actually a single, 3-d image.

Comment: Regarding numpy, basically you convert a SimpleITK image to a numpy array.  Then you convert the numpy array to an OpenCV image.  But again, the SimpleITK image is 3d, as is the numpy array.  So to get a stack of 2d OpenCV images you have to split the 3d image, either in SimpleITK or numpy.